# Filtrar por rango de fechas un archivo log de linux

Tags: linux

Quisiera extraer información de un archivo log desde una fecha especifica hasta el final y guardarlo en otro archivo.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Mi log es el siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Podrías intentar con grep, pero no sabría como buscar un rango de fechas, he visto con la fecha actual, pero no con un rango

Comment: Tendrías que mostrarnos el formato de tu log.

Comment: Te dejo el comando para sacar rangos en la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución mas simple que se me ocurre es usar la opcion A de grep indicandole que muestre un numero de lineas después de encontrar una coincidencia , indicandole en ese numero el numero total de lineas con el comando wc . La solucion quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
grep -A $(wc -l (fichero)) -e (Fecha) (fichero) > resultado.txt
```

De esta forma despues de una coincidencia imprimira todo lo que haya a continuación.

Si lo que deseas es un rango de fechas, el comando seria el siguiente:

```
grep -A $(wc -l (fichero)) -e (Fecha_inicio) (fichero) | grep -B $(wc -l fichero) -v (Fecha_fin)> resultado.txt
```

Con la opción B de grep imprimes un numero de lineas antes de cada coincidencia. Igualmente indicamos el total de las lineas del fichero y con la opcion 'v' invertimos la busqueda. Por lo que mostrará todo lo anterior a la primera coincidencia.

Comment: Hola en que formato debe estar la fecha. En mi log las fechas se encuentra de la siguiente manera.

Thu Feb 20 00:15:05 2020
Archived Log entry 30415 added for thread 1 sequence 114373 ID 0xa671fd8f dest 1:
Thu Feb 20 01:00:04 2020
ALTER SYSTEM ARCHIVE LOG
Thu Feb 20 01:00:04 2020

Comment: Hola buenas @Edward Raymundo, el formato de la fecha debe ser el que tu tengas, por eso esta de forma genérica. El comando grep, te permite buscar cualquier coincidencia, por lo que no necesitas usar el formato completo. En tu caso donde pone fecha podrías poner : Thu Feb 20 01:00:04 2020 o quizás  Thu Feb 20, también 20 01:00:04 2020, etc segun que quieras buscar , filtrar...

Comment: Hola @Alexmaiste, ejecute la siguiente linea grep -A $(wc -l (alert_upchp.log)) -e (Wed Mar 04) (alert_upchp.log) > resultado.txt y me aparecio el siguiente error:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Sabes a que se debe?

Comment: Buenas @EdwardRaymundo los parentesis no son necesarios, era una forma de indicar que esos campos son los que habria que cambiar. La fecha debes ponerla como texto, asi  -e (Wed Mar 04) -->  -e "Wed Mar 04"

Comment: PERFECTOOO!!! muchas gracias me ayudo. Pero un detalle mas que no es casi nada relevante pero porsiacaso. en el log generado veo que al inicio de cada registro me aparece el nombre del archivo del cual extraje es posible quitarlo y como: alert_upchp.log-Fri Mar 06 09:05:05 2020

Comment: Si @EdwardRaymundo añade la opcion -h para que no pinte el nombre de los ficheros. Puedes consultar esta y otras opciones desde el terminal de linux con : "man grep".

Answer (score 3):

Voy a realizar un ejemplo desde el ***syslog***, ya que es un log bastante genérico para que también puedas realizar las mismas pruebas.

Ejecuta el siguiente código y verás algo similar

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

***Output***:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mar  3 09:25:17 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092517.976796:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]
>   handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 Mar  3
>   09:25:40 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2889:2889:0303/092540.930821:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)]
>   [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <-
>   error from previous GL command Mar  3 09:25:57 dnlb
>   budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092557.805159:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]
>   handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 Mar  3
>   09:25:58 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092558.274676:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]
>   handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 Mar  3
>   09:25:58 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092558.382832:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]

En este caso voy a filtrar con `grep` la fecha de hoy. [03/03/20], en este caso lo haré así, sin embargo el `grep` puede estar acompañado de una variable llamada ***Fecha***.

Entonces para filtrar todo lo que pasó en un minuto, te repito lo que indiques en el `grep` puede ser una variable.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep "Mar  3 09:25"
```

***Output:***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mar  3 09:25:40 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2889:2889:0303/092540.930821:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)]
>   [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <-
>   error from previous GL command Mar  3 09:25:57 dnlb
>   budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092557.805159:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]
>   handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 Mar  3
>   09:25:58 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092558.274676:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]
>   handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 Mar  3
>   09:25:58 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092558.382832:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]
>   handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 Mar  3
>   09:25:58 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092558.572405:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]
>   handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 Mar  3
>   09:25:58 dnlb budgie-panel.desktop[2628]:
>   [2893:2897:0303/092558.813214:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)]
>   handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202

Ahora bien, para guardar todo el resultado es tan fácil como esto, en este caso no llevaría **-f**, porque no queremos seguir evaluando lo que vaya llegando:

```
tail var/log/syslog | grep "Mar  3 09:34" > info.txt
```

Si revisas el archivo info.txt mostrará toda la información del log.

Espero sea de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la respues pero tengo registros dentro de las fechas que no tienen fecha y es necesarios tambien visualizarlas.

mi log es el siguiente:
Thu Feb 20 00:15:05 2020
Archived Log entry 30415 added for thread 1 sequence 114373 ID 0xa671fd8f dest 1:
Thu Feb 20 01:00:04 2020
ALTER SYSTEM ARCHIVE LOG
Thu Feb 20 01:00:04 2020